How do I unblock macros that are blocked because the source of the file is untrusted?
Running Microsoft 365 Basic For Home and have very simply macro I created and it works flawlessly.  Saved to onedrive as file1.xlsm, when I re-open i get a red "security risk: microsoft has blocked macros from running because the source of this file is untrusted".
Microsoft forums state to simply go to file explorer > (right click) properties > general and check "Unblock" in security, but I don't have that option for some reason. Another user was able to open file and  simply "Enable macros" when opening the file and it works.  I don't have that "enable" option either.
I've also done File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings > Checked "Enable VBA Macros (Not recommended...)" and checked "Enable Excel 4.0 Macros...." and Checked "Trust Access to the VBA Project object model".
If saved on local drive and that added as a trusted site (File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted locations) then macros aren't block.
I've tried adding the one drive path to "trusted locations" and this doesn't seem to help, but I'm not sure i'm getting the path correct. Only thought is it doesn't like method in which I'm listing the one drive directory. I've tried it with both "c:\users...\directory" as well as right clicking on "one drive" and "copy link" where it includes the https://1drv.ms/f/

Just to check, when looking for the Unblock option, you are checking the file properties in File Explorer, not in Excel?

You are correct, File > Properties < General only goes to "attributes" and doesn't have the "Security" section with an "unblock"

In the Trust Center, Trusted Locations have you ticked "Allow Trusted Locations on my network (not recommended)"

Try https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/shared-onedrive-excel-macros-always-blocked-cant/affbbc0e-01dd-4e63-b98f-64238c70e5ed or https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/112ahmw/solution_enabling_macros_on_workbooks_from/

Yes - checked "allow trusted location on my network..."

@timWilliams - Thank you! Correct path for onedrive is https://d.docs.live.net

Open Excel
Navigate to Trust Center Settings
Developer > Macro Security OR
File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings
Go to Trusted Locations
Click "add new location" and put "https://d.docs.live.net" (no quotation marks) in the text box that pops up.
Be sure to click the checkbox "Subfolders of this location are also trusted"
Click Ok and restart excel.
